# Dependencies still exist in "dpkg -l" after running "apt-get remove dependencies-names"

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, xfce

I suspected that installing `xfce4` cause some issues in Ubuntu so I removed them using `apt-get remove xfce4 xfce4-goodeis`.

But when I ran 'dpkg -l' I still can see some libraries and packages for **xfce4**:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i xfce
rc  libexo-1-0:amd64                              0.10.2-2                                 amd64        Library with extensions for Xfce
rc  libgarcon-1-0                                 0.2.1-1                                  amd64        freedesktop.org compliant menu implementation for Xfce
rc  libxfce4ui-1-0                                4.11.0-0ubuntu1~ppa0.13.10.1             amd64        widget library for Xfce - Gtk+2 variant
rc  libxfce4ui-common                             4.11.0-0ubuntu1~ppa0.13.10.1             all          common files for libxfce4ui
rc  libxfce4util6                                 4.10.1-1                                 amd64        Utility functions library for Xfce4
rc  libxfcegui4-4                                 4.10.0-2                                 amd64        Basic GUI C functions for Xfce4
rc  libxfconf-0-2                                 4.10.0-2                                 amd64        Client library for Xfce4 configure interface
rc  mousepad                                      0.3.0-2                                  amd64        simple Xfce oriented text editor
rc  thunar                                        1.6.3-1ubuntu1                           amd64        File Manager for Xfce
rc  xfce4-appfinder                               4.10.1-1                                 amd64        Application finder for the Xfce4 Desktop Environment
rc  xfce4-clipman                                 2:1.2.3-2ubuntu1                         amd64        clipboard history utility
rc  xfce4-mixer                                   1:4.10.0-1ubuntu2                        amd64        Xfce mixer application
rc  xfce4-notes                                   1.7.7-3ubuntu2                           amd64        Notes application for the Xfce4 desktop
rc  xfce4-panel                                   4.10.1-1ubuntu1                          amd64        panel for Xfce4 desktop environment
rc  xfce4-power-manager                           1.2.0-2ubuntu1                           amd64        power manager for Xfce desktop
rc  xfce4-session                                 4.10.1-1ubuntu1                          amd64        Xfce4 Session Manager
rc  xfce4-settings                                4.11.1-0ubuntu1~ppa0.13.10.1             amd64        graphical application for managing Xfce settings
rc  xfce4-terminal                                0.6.2-3ubuntu1.1                         amd64        Xfce terminal emulator
rc  xfce4-volumed                                 0.2.0-0ubuntu1                           amd64        volume keys daemon
rc  xfdesktop4                                    4.11.2-0ubuntu1~ppa0.13.10.1             amd64        xfce desktop background, icons and root menu manager
rc  xfwm4                                         4.11.1-0ubuntu1~ppa0.13.10.1             amd64        window manager of the Xfce project
```

I copy-pasted all these packages\libraries to form an `apt-get remove` command to remove all of these dependencies, and the command ran normally, but running `dpkg -l | grep -i xfce` showed these dependencies again !

Why are these dependencies still installed ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the `rc` at the beginning of the list.

> `r`: Remove (marked for removal) 
>     `c`: Configuration files are present.

The difference between `apt-get remove` and `purge` (From `man apt-get`)

```
   remove
       remove is identical to install except that packages are removed instead of installed.
       Note the removing a package leaves its configuration files in system.

   purge
       purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any
       configuration files are deleted too).
```

As you choose to `apt-get remove`, your `dpkg -l` reflecting that. If you would have been used `apt-get purge` you could avoid such a situation. To get rid of these, try in terminal,

```
dpkg --list | grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

It will purge all the packages which are marked for removal. Before you purge them you can check the list which you are going to purge using,

```
dpkg --list | grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3
```

I guess you have no other package remain marked for removal except those are from `xfce`. If you are not sure about it. Use the following instead,

```
dpkg --list | grep -i xfce | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

Comment: The same thing, slightly more compact and robust: `dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 4):

The dependencies are *not* still installed.

When you run `dpkg -l`, [`dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) calls [`dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html). Entries in the first column (where you're seeing `rc`) consist of two one-letter abbreviations.

The first letter specifies the desired state of the package as specified by package management actions. `r` means it is intended to be removed. This means it either

- is actually removed, *or*
- has been specified for removal but is not yet fully removed or the removal failed.

To see which is the case, consult the second letter, `c`. This indicates what, from the package, is installed. If *no files of any kind* are present, the second letter reads `n` (though actually, since you're running `dpkg -l`/`dpkg --list` without arguments and then parsing the output, the entry would simply not appear at all if there were no files).

`c` means all that's installed are *configuration files*. Usually it's not safe to assume a user wants to remove these when uninstalling a package. If you want to remove them, you can pass the `--purge` flag to `apt-get` (or specify the `purge` action instead of the `remove` action) when uninstalling packages.

To remove these configuration files, even though the packages themselves are uninstalled, you can still purge them, either with `dpkg -P ...` or `apt-get purge ...`. Using `dpkg` to purge many packages is [can be somewhat complicated](https://askubuntu.com/a/406804/22949) but `apt-get` will match [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (as `grep` does) for package names. Assuming you want a single short command that removes all these packages and *assuming you really want to remove all packages with `xfce` in their name, this will do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get purge xfce.\*
```

Note that the `*` is *not* a wildcard, `.\*` matches zero or more of any character. The `.` is essential for making this happen (see below). This regexp is equivalent to just `xfce`, but it's *recognized* as a regexp by `apt-get` because it contains the special character `*`.

(Similarly, if you used `xfce\*` or `xfce*` it would remove all packages with `xfc` in the name. People have tried to get rid of Wine by removing `wine*`, which has resulted in every package with `win` anywhere in the name being removed, breaking their systems!)

Or if you prefer to do the purge with `dpkg`, an easily comprehended way (which I think thereby reduces mistakes) to do so is to tell `dpkg-list` how to format its own output:

```
sudo dpkg -P `dpkg-query -f='${Package}\n' -W | grep xfce`
```

Or you can simply run `dpkg-query -f='${Package} ' -W | grep xfce`, letting you examine the output to make sure it's what you want, and then copy and paste that space-delimited list of packages into a `sudo apt-get purge` or `sudo dpkg -P` command.